# Caused by : java. awt. HeadlessException

Tags: macros, awt, ado

Observed headless exception during the execution in ADO where the same has perfectly working as expected in local host.

We are using macro based excel in Azure DevOps.

Can you share solutions?

Logs
Caused by : java.awt.HeadlessException
No X11 DISPLAY variable set but this program performed an operation

Trying to access macro based excel in ADO

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.